# Change a HTML element in app.component dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have implemented angular2 routing and its working perfect. Then i got this crazy thought and couldn't find a solution for that.

> **Question**: I have an **app.component.html** page with a **navbar** and a
>   **jumbotron** bootstrap element. The navbar has two links, one for **home**
>   **page**, and the other for **settings** **page**. I need to change the jumbotron
>   element to display "**You are in Home page**" from the HomeComponent variable when home link is clicked
>   and display "**You are in Settings page**" from the SettingsComponent variable, when settings link is clicked.
>   I know its possible but don't know how.

**Visual Representation:**

[image]

Here is my snippet:

**app.component.html**

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Darth</a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a [routerLink]="['']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Home</a></li>
                <li><a [routerLink]="['settings']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']">Settings</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

I have uploaded the entire project in [my github repo here](https://github.com/darthranjith/masterLayoutDemo)

Comment: It's discouraged to repeat tags in the question title.

Comment: I'm sorry, removed the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the problem but you can always use a shared service that holds the status and use `*ngIf` to show/hide something depending on that state. See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: The proper way of doing it is to use services as outlined in "[components communication through <router-outlet>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834286/components-communication-through-router-outlet)"

One simple but not-so-clean way of doing it is to detect url changes by listening on router events.

You component code becomes

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {Router, NavigationEnd} from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  currentMessage:string = "Hello, World";
  constructor(private activeRoute:Router) {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.activeRoute.events.subscribe(this.onUrlChange.bind(this))
  }

  onUrlChange(ev) {
    if(ev instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      let url = ev.url;
      if(url.indexOf('settings') != -1)  {
          this.currentMessage = "Settings";
      } else {
        this.currentMessage = "Home";
      }

    }
  }
}
```

And you modify your jumptron to read the "currentMessage" variable

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>{{currentMessage}}</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @MostafaAbdelraouf. Both the techniques worked great. But as you said, I prefered the shared service way for component communication.