# Angular 2 - How to change header when switch to different route /different page(beginner level)

Tags: angular, typescript

## SOLVED

 
I have few components :
- home component, default header, detail component, detail header component 
Both headers have different layouts
Let say at Home page, it will display 'Default header',
When user at Detail Page, it will display 'Detail Header'
So my logic is to do some **if else** in **app.component.ts**
Unfortunately, it doesn't show as expected.
How to do in Angular2? I have problem to switch the header.

This is my app.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: ['./main.css'],
  template: `
    <div class="main-body">
      <app-header *ngIf="!showHeaderB()"></app-header>
      <detail-header *ngIf="showHeaderB()"></detail-header>
      <div class="container">
        <small><api-error></api-error></small></div>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      </div>
      <app-footer></app-footer>
      <template ngbModalContainer></template>
    </div>
  `
})

export class AppComponent {
  showHeaderB(){
    if (this.router.url.startsWith('/detail/')) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331382/change-a-html-element-in-app-component-dynamically

Comment: So, what's the problem with the code you posted. What are you doing, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead?

Comment: Sorry for confusing
First - I have a few headers for different pages. 
Home page use 'Header A'
Detail page use 'Header B'
So, when user at Home Page, it will show 'Header A'
If user at Detail Page, it will show 'Header B'
I'm thinking to do some logic in app.component.ts, and still stuck on it. 
I  not sure the way that I did is correct or wrong and some how it doesn't show as expected.

Comment: If it doesn't show as expected, it can mean 2 things. 1. there is an exception, and you should see it in your console. 2. your method returns true instead of returning false, or vice-versa. So, check what the url is. Use your debugger. Add console.log() statements in the code.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38644314/changing-the-page-title-using-the-angular-2-new-router/38652281#38652281

Answer (score 0):

Have a page-header as a separate component.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'page-header',
  template: `
    <div> {{title}}</div> 
  `,
})
export class PageHeader {

  @Input() title:string="";

}
```

In each of your component you should include that component and assign title to it.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'component-1',
  template: `
    <div>
      <page-header title="pageTitle"> </page-header>
      ...
    </div>
  `,
})

export class Component1 {

pageTitle:string;

}

@Component({
  selector: 'component-2',
  template: `
    <div>
      <page-header title="pageTitle"> </page-header>
      ...
    </div>
  `,
})

export class Component2 {

pageTitle:string;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I'm really appreciate it, but question is not to change the 'page title'. I mean to show different headers because my headers have different layouts when route to different pages. :)

Comment: you are looking **not to change the header of which component** and when?

Comment: For example, **Home page** shows **Default Header**, when user at **Detail Page**, it will shows **Detail Header**. The rest of the pages will show **Default Header**

Comment: this you should handle by separating components as needed. I will update the post with a demo in sometime. hangon

Comment: For your problem, @Aravind 's solution is much simpler and suitable. Additionally parsing the title value will help you better.

Comment: Thank you so much. There is an existing page for your reference: Take a look at headers there
Home page = [link] (http://jobscentral.com.sg)
Detail page = [link] (http://jobscentral.com.sg/job/driver-goods-delivery-jjh6rr79w0pry9xggb8?APath=2.21.0.0.0&showNewJDP=yes&IPath=JRKCVT)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your showHeaderB() method into this

lets say, that you have your url like this localhost:8080/..../..../detail/....
your position of detail is 4, so you set parameter for position 4

```
showerHeaderB(){
    if (this.router.url.startsWith('/detail', 4)) {
        return true;
     } else {
            return false;
      }
    }
```