# How to notify another component and pass data into it

Tags: angular

I'm trying to learn angular 2. I have imported [ng2-upload-file](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload). Now, I have an upload button in one of my component. In the backend, I analyze the uploaded file and change it and then display the result in another component.

this is the function called when upload is completed.

```
this.uploader.onCompleteItem = (item: any, response: any, status: any, headers: any) => {
    let responsePath = JSON.parse(response);
};
```

Now, I want my other component noticed when upload is completed. Also, response of uploaded data should be displayed in that component. How I can do that?

Comment: You can create one shared service to handle this. check https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service

Comment: Is your other component a parent component of this one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [components communication through <router-outlet>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39834286/components-communication-through-router-outlet)

Comment: i've followed the cookbook and now it works. thank you all guys. ranakrunal9, NexusDuck, tibbus